# How to compensate for fixed header using CSS smooth scrolling?

Tags: css, reactjs

I added smooth scrolling through CSS by using this code -

```
html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
```

My header is fixed and is 75px in length. I have a link with an anchor tag to go to a different part of the page, but when that is clicked it is off by 75px because of the header.

I know I can use jQuery to offset for the 75px, but this is a React app and I'd rather avoid using jQuery if possible.

Is there a way to offset using CSS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `scroll-margin-top` in css:

```
scroll-margin-top: -75px;
```